# JavaFX Freezes Mac When Running Second Time

Tags: java, macos, javafx

The following completely freezes my MacBook Pro when I run it the second time (both in Eclipse and directly from the command-line). First time the GUI is displayed and the app runs as expected, but when I then stop and re-run it exactly the same way it freezes the computer completely.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Crash!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String... arguments) {
        launch(arguments);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea? I'm thinking the solution may be some combination of –launcher.secondThread, -XstartOnFirstThread, -XstartOnSecondThread like when running a Swing GUI with OSGI on a Mac, but I haven't had any success.

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing and found out that it is a problem with OS X switching graphic cards - i fixed the problem by installing gfx.io and forcing OS X to one graphic card

Comment: Although I haven't tried this, it looks like this is certainly related to the problem. Thanks to your comment I found that turning off 'automatic graphics switching' (System Preferences > Energy Saver) stops the OS from freezing. It might affect battery life, but...